# template alias in specialized class

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

The following code gives the error (in line where i define test):

> error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '<'
>   note: see reference to class template instantiation 'ptc::Produce' being compiled
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. 
>   Note: C++ does not support default-int

Does anybody know why this happens?
Compiler is VC2015 CTP1.

Edit: the error must happen in phase1 of the template parsing, because it occurs even I never instantiate the class Produce.

```
namespace OrderPolicy
{
    struct Unordered {};
    struct Ordered {};
};

template <typename TOrderPolicy>
struct OrderManager {};

template<>
struct OrderManager<OrderPolicy::Unordered>
{
    template <typename TItem>
    using item_t = TItem;
};

template<>
struct OrderManager<OrderPolicy::Ordered> 
{
    template <typename TItem>
    using item_t = TItem*;
};

template<typename TOrderPolicy>
struct Produce : public OrderManager<TOrderPolicy>
{
    item_t<int> test;
    //using item_type = item_t<int>;
};
```

Edit2: it works when I change the last part of the code to

```
struct Produce : public OrderManager<OrderPolicy::Ordered>
{
    item_t<int> test;
    //using item_type = item_t<int>;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
item_t<int> test;
```

That names a dependent template type from a base class. In this case, you need to tell the compiler both that `item_t` is a type in your base class, and that it's a template.

The direct way to do this is using [`typename` and `template`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords):

```
typename OrderManager<TOrderPolicy>::template item_t<int> test;
```

As you can see, this will quickly become unreadable. I would make some local aliases to make the code neater:

```
using Base = OrderManager<TOrderPolicy>;
using item_type = typename Base::template item_t<int>;
item_type test;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use:

```
typename OrderManager<TOrderPolicy>::template item_t<int>
```

in place of:

```
item_t<int> test;
```

Comment: *"Type aliases are not imported from the base class"*, why? I think the problem is that the base class is a dependent one, so the name is not looked up there

Comment: Yes, I checked it. Aliases are indeed imported, it just needs to know that its a template.

Answer (score 0):

wow, learning never stops. Until now I did not see the keyword template used in this context.